# firebase analytics: find useruid for app_remove

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I am using Firebase (react-native-firebase if it matters).

In the events section of the console, I see that the app_remove event tracks uninstalls.

I want to find out what specific users uninstalled the app, and thus triggered the app_remove.

I want to see past data as well, not just future data.

How do I see the specific useruid for the users?
If I cannot see in the console, can I do this in code?

Many thanks!

Comment: im just not able to get the database works with android. did u manage to get it working?

Comment: Yes, Firebase Realtime Database works for me on a React Native project on Android. what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bro.
Firebase is an amazing project, and many thanx to [invertase](https://invertase.io/) they bring it to React-Native.

Dashboard you watching is based on [Analytics](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/analytics/reference/analytics) tool, that goes with [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) lib. With Analytics tool you are able to attach some specific knowledge to each(even implicit) events that tracks in Dashboard.

eg: `analytics.setUserId` will add and show **id** of user that dispatched some event.

Comment: I agree with invertase doing a great job. I don't understand the answer. I am using firebase.analitycs(); https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/analytics/reference/analytics . How do I see all the app_uninstall events that have been tracked until now (before I write this code)? Thanks

Comment: @NicoaraTalpes the question is "how to add a custom property to already despatched and stored event"? I think the answer is nohow. Never had this case, maybe firebase will bond some events to the properties, but if it is - its implicit feature.